# how to use jquery mobile asp.net mvc 4 to download and display pdf memory stream data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, pdf-generation

I have a desktop/mobile web app that needs to display a pdf stream on the target device.  I now have this working on the desktop using the jquery dialog.  For mobile tho...my html View page has the following link:

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("PdfView", new { id = @paystub.PayStub_ID})">View PDF</a>
```

And that correctly takes me into the Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult PdfView(string id = "")
    {
        PayStubDataEntity ps = PayStubAccess.GetPayStubByID(new Guid(id), new Guid(Session["Session_Application_UserID"].ToString()));
        WebHelper.SetHeadersForDownload(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, "application/pdf", "PayStub.pdf", false);
        MemoryStream pdfMemoryStream = SendPayStubToBrowserAsPdf(ps);
        //WebHelper.SendFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, "application/pdf", "PayStub.pdf", false, pdfMemoryStream);
        return File(pdfMemoryStream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

But nothing ever shows up on my iphone emulator (electric plum). No error messages.  I am not sure where the output s/b going or how to view it?  Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: have tried it on android emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

We have this same issue with android phones and there can be two issues going on. If the website uses ssl and the phone you are on does not accept it as a valid ssl, it will say downloading pdf in the manager, but it never completes a download.
The second issue is the file you are sending to the phone needs to be named in order to download properly to the phone.

Ex: return File(pdfMemoryStream, "application/pdf", fileDownloadName:"PayStub.pdf");

I would suggest using Google Chrome for phone emulation. When you change the settings, it will behave similarly to the phone and you can debug easily.
For example, when I set Google Chrome to the mobile phone user agent Android 4.0.2, it will download the pdf, instead of displaying within the web browser. When it does that, I know it is working locally. It also has iPhone emulation.